# ps output differs when run from command line and from script

Tags: ps, columns, cut

I have to create list of PID's of the running processes.

Here is the script

```
ps
echo "fields are "
ps | cut -d' ' -f1
```

`ps` is showing

```
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
 2168 pts/4    00:00:00 sh
 2177 pts/4    00:00:00 mailx
 5191 pts/4    00:00:00 sh
 6494 pts/4    00:00:00 sh
 6495 pts/4    00:00:00 ps
12154 pts/4    00:00:00 sh
12172 pts/4    00:00:00 mailx
15618 pts/4    00:00:00 bash
```

But the output of cut pipeline is just

```
12154
12172
15618
```

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that `cut` uses a single space character as a delimiter, but as the column name and the 4 digit PIDs are right aligned there are multiple leading spaces which cause `cut` to output an empty line.

An alternative approach is to use `awk`, which copes better with this kind of input:

```
ps | awk '{ print $1 }'
```

In the case of `ps` in particular [mindthemonkey's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/90372/43779) is a better approach.

Answer (score 2):

For the full list:

```
ps -eo pid
```

Or just your processes:

```
ps -o pid
```

Answer (score 0):

As a third choice, you could also use `grep`:

```
ps | grep -oP '^\s*\d+'
```

The `-P` enables Perl regular expressions (for the `\s`,`\d` and `+`) and the `-o` causes `grep` to print only the matched section pf matching lines.